# Python to print first three lines of text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


url = "https://alta.ge/phones-and-communications/smartphones.html"
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

a = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'ty-grid-list__item-name'})
for smartphone in a:
    a = smartphone.find('a').get_text()
    print(a)
```

this is my code when i run it prints names of every item. i only want to print first 3 items, how do i do that?

Comment: A simple for loop would be a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
for smartphone in a:
    a = smartphone.find('a').get_text()
    print(a)
```

You can try to replace it with:

```
for smartphone in a:
    if count < 3:
        a = smartphone.find('a').get_text()
        print(a)
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using these codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


url = "https://alta.ge/phones-and-communications/smartphones.html"
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

a = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'ty-grid-list__item-name'})
for smartphone in a[:3]: 
    a = smartphone.find('a').get_text()
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this part of your code:

```py
for smartphone in a:
    a = smartphone.find('a').get_text()
    print(a)
```

**With this:**

```py
count = 0
for smartphone in a:
    if count < 3:
        a = smartphone.find('a').get_text()
        print(a)
        count += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace

```
for smartphone in a:
```

with

```
for smartphone in a[:3]:
```

to loop trough 3 elements in list only